# resize with custom UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've searched for a long time and found nothing. maybe i didnt get the keyword of this, hope you can help me fix this problem:
[image: original]

this is original view, but when i turn on the Hotspot.. it will be like this:
[image: crop!]

how can i deal with this? `autoresizingMask`? Ive try it and it didnt work.
i used a custom tab bar and found it won't appear this problem when i use `UITabBarController`

Comment: add status bar to the scene or nib you are working on

Comment: nib view controller view -> attribute inspector -> simulated matrix -> status bar -> set to black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the frame of subviews in `- (void)layoutSubviews`,

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
   //tabbar.frame = ….
}
```